# Save an animation on Python

Tags: ffmpeg, python

I am trying to save a simple animation maid by a Python code using the following commands:

```
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                   frames = 100, interval = 20, blit = True)
    anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

But Python returns:

```
C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py:971: UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-fd8a28a3225c>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('D:/Documents/Informatique/Spyder/test_anim2d.py', wdir='D:/Documents/Informatique/Spyder')

File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "D:/Documents/Informatique/Spyder/test_anim2d.py", line 34, in <module>
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 978, in save
raise ValueError("Cannot save animation: no writers are "

ValueError: Cannot save animation: no writers are available. Please install ffmpeg to save animations.
```

However, I have installed ffmpeg so I have no clue...

Maybe it is in the wrong directory? I installed it in *C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\scripts*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg file should be in the same folder that you have your python program in. Try copying it to there and see if that works.

Comment: @Nausicaa when you downloaded the zip folder the ffmpeg came in, did you extract the zip folder and then copy and paste the ffmpeg file in because you should just copy and paste the file directly from the zip folder without extracting it. I was just now able to create and save an animation using this example [link](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) but replaced `plt.show()` with `ani.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])`. If this website doesn't help you, I would be happy to help you more if you are willing to send me your code.

Comment: I downloaded the zip folder and extracted it in C:\ and add its path to the system as it is explained here [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows). Then I installed it with the cmd prompt as they explain here [link] (https://superuser.com/questions/1082130/installing-python-script-for-ffmpeg)

Comment: I also tried to copy the example in your link remplacing `plt.show()` by `ani.save(...)` and I've got the same, my code is basically the same actually.

Comment: @Nausicaa There's likely an issue with your ffmpeg file then. Like I said before, when you downloaded the zip folder, don't extract it just copy the file directly from it. I uploaded my ffmpeg to google drive for you and created a sharable link so you can download it. Try using that file and if that doesn't work, then like I said, I would be happy to help more if you send me you entire code. One final thing I suggest is to make sure everything is imported correctly too. Here is the link to my [ffmpeg file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EfGJzFGS7XXMPCL6HEJ_MdMRDYf2Nqb2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I downloaded your file and copied it into the directory where python is stocked, Then I installed ffmpeg, I copied the directory where ffmpeg-normalize.exe was installed, into the path and I installed it via the cmd prompt and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help!! :)

Comment: @Nausicaa no problem can you make sure to mark it as the answer for me.